# Trigger CSS animation with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I used the CSS here:

```
@keyframes themesappear{
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    } 100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes themesappear{
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    } 100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

and the Javascript here:

```
var theme = function() {
    document.getElementById('themes').style.animation = "themesMappear 2s forwards;";
    document.getElementById('themes').style.WebkitAnimation = "themesappear 2s forwards;";
};
```

in attempt to make the div with the id "themes" fade in and appear...

The problem is the onclick does not work, and neither does the opacity change, how can I fix this?  You can see the website [here](https://caa8edf10c487b5ff2dc93e7192b6b4ab1ae15da-www.googledrive.com/host/0B-Yxt1Eo-wZVa05aNzM2alk3Rnc)

How I used the onlclick: `<h1 id = "WM" onclick = "theme()">Change Theme</h1>`

Comment: Can you show how you are using the `onclick`?

Answer (score 5):

few things

1. you seem to have a typo (`themesMappear` instead of `themesappear`)
2. you have a semicolon at the end of the rule, which makes it invalid and therefore not added. It should be `"themesMappear 2s forwards"`, not  `"themesMappear 2s forwards;"`
3. you should really create a class with those rules, and then just toggle the class with those styles via JS

Comment: Thanks!  Any idea why the `onclick` isn't triggering?